# Do any two structures of a language with constants have a common non-trivial substructure?

Tags: model-theory

Suppose you have two $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$. Extend the language to include new distinct constant symbols $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ and take $\mathcal{C}=\langle c_1^{\mathcal{M}},...,c_n^{\mathcal{M}}\rangle$--the substructure generated by the interpretations of the $c_i$ in $\mathcal{M}$. Then $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathcal{C}$. So up to isomorphism, we have a common $\mathcal{L}(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$-structure.

It's a bit unclear to me why I can't then take an $\mathcal{L}$-reduct of $\mathcal{C}$ and deduce that $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ have a common non-trivial $\mathcal{L}$-substructure. But the conclusion that any to $\mathcal{L}$-structures have a common non-trivial substructure seems wrong to me.

Comment: Why does $\mathcal{N}$ have to contain an isomorphic copy of $\mathcal{C}$? Say $G$ and $H$ are two groups, and $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are some elements in $G$. There's no reason that $H$ should contain a copy of $\langle c_1, \ldots, c_n \rangle$. Am I misunderstanding something simple?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor This could be wrong. It seemed intuitive to me since you should be able to map everything from $\langle c_1^{\mathcal{M}},\ldots,c_n^{\mathcal{M}}\rangle$ to $\langle c_1^{\mathcal{N}},\ldots,c_n^{\mathcal{N}}\rangle$ naturally, but maybe it's not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Let me expand on my earlier comment, because your intuition is sound: something has gone wrong here.

I think the misunderstanding here has to do with how $\langle c_1^\mathcal{M}, \ldots, c_n^\mathcal{M} \rangle$ is built. It's the smallest substructure of $\mathcal{M}$ containing all the $c_1, \ldots, c_n$. In particular, the elements that wind up in $\langle c_1^\mathcal{M}, \ldots, c_n^\mathcal{M} \rangle$, and the relations between the $c_k^\mathcal{M}$ are *heavily* dependent on $\mathcal{M}$.

For example, say $\mathcal{M} = C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$, and $\mathcal{N} = C_3$. Then say that $c^\mathcal{M}$ picks out the generator of $\mathcal{M}$ and $c^\mathcal{N}$ picks out a generator of $\mathcal{N}$. Then $\langle c^\mathcal{M} \rangle = C_2$ (the smallest subgroup containing $c^\mathcal{M}$) and $\langle c^\mathcal{N} \rangle = C_3$ (the smallest subgroup containing $c^\mathcal{N}$).

Of course, these substructures $\langle c^\mathcal{M} \rangle$ and $\langle c^\mathcal{N} \rangle$ are *not* isomorphic! The issue is that, even though they're both generated by one element, the *relations* that the elements satisfy are different because they're living inside of different groups. For instance, $(c^\mathcal{M})^2 = e^\mathcal{M}$ while $(c^\mathcal{N})^2 \neq e^\mathcal{N}$. Unfortunately, the notation $\langle c^\mathcal{M} \rangle$ doesn't really indicate this, especially if you leave out the superscripts reminding you what structure you're in.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you, this clears up my confusion.